# How to check the value in textbox in gridview using jquery in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery

I used gridview to display some products and used textbox inside a gridview to enter the quantity. I have written a jquery to display an alert box if the textbox is empty. But while displaying alert box the page reloads. But i want to display the alert box without reloading. Since it was in Master page, i dont know how to do it.

Comment: paste html and script code here

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post your source code here. It gives a clarity to the problem you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

may be this will help you
 use return false after your alert syntax like this

```
alert('Please provide value');
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a messagebox popup to inform the user that some field does not have a (correct) value is often perceived as annoying to former user as it completely blocks the browser and forces the user to first click "Ok" before she can do anything else.

I didn't find a good reliable source except for [this](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/08/extensive-guide-web-form-usability/) to back up my bold statement:

> **Error message** This notifies the user that an error has occurred, and it usually prevents them from proceeding further in the form.
>   Emphasize error messages through color (typically red), familiar
>   iconography (such as a warning sign), prominence (typically at the top
>   of the form or beside where the error occurred), large font, or a
>   combination of these.
>
> **Success message** Use this to notify users that they have reached a
>   meaningful milestone in the form. If the form is lengthy, a success
>   message encourages the user to continue filling it out. Like error
>   messages, success messages should be prominent. **But they should not
>   hinder the user from continuing.**

A better way might be to use a non-blocking message and stopping the submit. [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) is an excellent framework to validate your user input.